# SD card data not getting erased

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, sd-card

I have `Samsung Galaxy J26` with `SanDisk` 16gb memory card. Although the card seems ok I have facing one weird problem. If I delete something from the card and check the memory status it doesn't seem to get change. It should show more memory as I have cleared some space but it doesn't. In the end, I have to format the SD card for further use even it doesn't have anything.

Comment: After formatting, is the problem solved or does it repeat? It's not clear

Comment: If that is the case, try formatting on a PC and see if it helps

Comment: After formating also same problem